# Concatenate a column in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, join

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Computer, App
PC1, Software1
PC1, Software2
PC1, Software3
PC2, Software1
PC2, Software4
PC2, Software5
```

And I want a CSV file like this:

```
Computer, Apps
PC1, Software1;Software2;Software3
PC2, Software1;Software4;Software5
```

I tried using powershell and it almost gets me there:

```
import-csv input.csv | group-object Computer
```

But it gives me the computer name and a table with the computer name and the apps (which is what I started with)... Any way to break that down further to get at the actual strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need to group by `Computer`, and join the `App` values in the group.

```
$a = Import-Csv .\mycsvfile.csv

$a |
Group-Object Computer |
Select-Object @{name="Computer";expression={$_.Name}}, @{name="Apps";expression={($_.Group | % { $_.App }) -join ';'}} |
Export-Csv .\mycsvfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

mycsvfile.csv

```
"Computer","Apps"
"PC1","Software1;Software2;Software3"
"PC2","Software1;Software4;Software5"
```

Comment: Perfect! I never tried using a code block inside one of those select constructs. That's nice!

Answer (score 1):

Another way, just for variety:

```
Import-Csv .\input.csv |
    Group-Object Computer |
    % {[pscustomobject]@{ Computer = $_.Name; Apps = ($_.Group).App -join ';'}} |
    Export-Csv .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This requires PowerShell 3.